# Express Node accept request after running initial code

Tags: node.js, express

I have an app with express and socket.io. I make request to 3d party api and store the response data in array:

```
var codes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var results=[]

var calls = codes.map(code=>{
    var url = 'http://example.com?code='+code           
    return axios.get(url);
});                     

axios.all(calls)
.then(function(data){
    results=data
})
```

But I use results array in my routes - I send it to all the user in response.
How to make sure that after restart - the user will not get an empty array?

Comment: you need a database.

Comment: I want to store in database only `codes`. But the `results` array - must be filled with data from axios response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will require a database or some sort of a server. When nodejs restarts, it starts the whole script over. This means that it will redefine all of your variables, and restart all the processes.

If you want it to start where you left off, you could use a server that runs different code based on the url. You could also write some data to a file before you restart, then you can look at the data and run different code based on what that says.

hope this helps!